# How to set MenuItem to corrent width in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I have a 1000px wide div, which contains a menu control. Inside this menu, I have 5 items (links). I want to use whole length of line, so in css file is wide of every item set to 200px.

```
.level1
{
  border-width: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #99FF66;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #FF0000;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
 }
```

However, when page is loaded, I get two rows, because the last item doesn't fit.
[image]

See, that inserted black line is 200px wide (and the link "vzkazy" is longer). So the question is: Why is the MenuItem wider ? And how to set it's wide to 200px ? Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible you could also add the output HTML for that section from the rendered source? If you can, you could either put it on http://jsfiddle.net/ and link to it here, or embed it above (but that looks a lot uglier).

Comment: so do you want to show all 5 items in a row with 200px width so you can cover 1000px am i correct?

Comment: in your code at jsFiddle you applied your level1 class to ul and all anchor tags so i think you need not to applied same style to your ul tag you can do somethiong: ul.level1 li{ here your code }

Comment: i am not able to find your css code at jsfiddle.is that your complete code related to this issue?

Comment: I will try the ul.level etc...

Comment: That was perfect shot !!  Problem solved. Post your quote about ul.level1, so I can add you some points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your code at jsFiddle you applied your level1 class to ul and all anchor tags so i think you need not to applied same style to your ul tag you can do somethiong: ul.level1 li{ here your code }